# Manual formatting

Tags: ios, swift

Newbie in Swift, please help me out, when I type . or after .0 or .00 it should reflect with 0.00, but this is not visible to myTxtField.text.

Following is my code -

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // return NO to not change text
        //Decimal
      switch string {
      case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",".":
            currentString += string
            print(currentString)
            formatCurrency(currentString)

      default:
            if string.characters.count == 0 && currentString.characters.count != 0 {
                currentString = String(currentString.characters.dropLast())
                formatCurrency(currentString)
         }
     }

     return false 
}

func formatCurrency(string: String) {

      let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
      formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
      formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
      formatter.roundingMode = .RoundDown
      formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
      let numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)
      let tAmount:String!
      if string == "" {
         myTxtField.text = ""
         tAmount = "$" + formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
      }else {
         myTxtField.text = "$" + formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
         tAmount = "$" + formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
      }
      print("value=\(HManager.convertCurrencyToDouble(tAmount))")

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to see fraction digits? But you are rounding them.

Comment: no  ! if i type 1.00 its coming only 1 in myTxtField ,its ignoring . and 0 ,if i type 1.08 then its showing perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method and `editingDidEnd` to achieve your goal.

- The `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to limit the text field to accepting only number and decimal point `.`.
- The `editingDidEnd` is to format the text field with 2 decimal digits.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

        if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) != nil {
            // If the added character is not a number
            if string == "." {
                // If the added character is the decimal point
                let countDots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1
                if countDots == 0 {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func editingDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
        // Format the input with 2 decimal digits.
        if let input = sender.text, let inputDouble = Double(input) {
            sender.text = String(format: "%.2f", inputDouble)
        } else {
            sender.text = "0.00"
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order to add a currency symbol ($) and remove the fractional part if needed, you need to have a function to check whether the input is `double` or `Int`.

```
@IBAction func editingDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Format the input with 2 decimal digits.
    if let input = sender.text, let number = Double(input) {
        if canConvertToInt(number) {
            sender.text = "$\(Int(number))"
        } else {
            sender.text = "$\(number)"
        }
    } else {
        sender.text = "$0"
    }
}

// Check if the number is not decimal
func canConvertToInt(_ double: Double) -> Bool {
    return rint(double) == double
}
```

Comment: Thanx ! I am using for currency formatting.does it will work??

Comment: By "currency formatting", you mean sth like this **$0.15**?

Comment: Yes !! Try this 1.00 its shows 1 , 0.00 its shows 0 i want that if i enter 0.0 or 0.00 it shows same in textfield

Comment: Problem is only after dot Enter 1.00 = 1 ,Enter 1.08 = 1.08 ,Enter 0.0 = 0,Enter 0.00 = 0 ,user cannot enter 00 after dot

Comment: Explaining the above Problem in detail
Enter-> 1.00        Result->$1 ,Enter->1.01     Result->  $1.01  // in this case value 0 is shown if i entered 1
Enter->0.00      Result-> $0,
Enter->$01234.12    Result->$1,234.12
Only problem is after dot when enter 0 .Sorry in above i missed $ sign

Comment: I updated my answer as you requested. Adding commas `,` to separate off thousands should not be difficult, so you can do it yourself.